# Play form and GET request with parameter error

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

In play framework routes get compilation error

error on here

```
GET  /allFriends    controllers.Application.listAllFriends(userId:Long?=)
```

template

```
 @(myFriends: List[MyFriend])
    @import helper._
    @import helper.twitterBootstrap._


    @for(myFriend <- myFriends){
        @myFriend.friend_Id <br>
    }
```

error

```
string matching regex `[^),?=\n]' expected but `)' found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your routes file: if you use `?=`, you need a default value for `userId` in `controllers.Application.listAllFriends(userId:Long?= <here>)`.

If you look at the [Play Routing documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting), you will see that:

```
GET  /allFriends    controllers.Application.listAllFriends(userId:Long)
```

will match `/allFriends?userId=1` but not `/allFriends`, and

```
GET  /allFriends    controllers.Application.listAllFriends(userId:Long ?= -1)
```

will also match `/allFriends` with the default value of `-1`.